# Guidance for Success

Tags: path

Can you put a formula field in Guidance for Success? Not the Key fields section. I want Guidance for Success to change dynamically based on a picklist value? Is there a way around it, if it is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can able to build/Create a path based on any specific field. Since path settings are used for provide the specific stage value with required fields (with Guidance of success description)

Ref :
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sales_admin_optimize_salesforce_for_selling/sales_admin_optimize_for_selling_unit_1

But you can add a `Validation rule` to specify the `stage` values only occur for their specific `piclist` value ( from your custom `piclist` field)

Or You can use use any automation like `flow` to update the `Stage` field based on the `piclist` field value (on after update)

Please let me know if it helps.